# System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' on Frame Navigation

Tags: c#, uwp

I want to know how can I navigate between pages in a frame sending parameters.

I've tried this on my Navigation View:

```
 if (tag != null)
        {
            switch (tag)
            {
                case "Users":
                    User user = new User();
                    MainFrame.Navigate(typeof(UserManagementPage), user);
                    break;
            }
```

In the View (Page) I just have this code:

```
 public UserManagementPage(User user)
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }
```

When I click on the `NavigationViewItem` that was supposed to navigate the frame to the `UserManagementPage` the app throws the following exception:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an
> instance of an object.'

at `MainFrame.Navigate(typeof(UserManagementPage), user);`

I've tried to remove the parameter from the page constructor and it worked fine so I think the problem is on the way I'm trying to send the parameter.

Anyone knows how can I do this right?

PS: The problem isn't on the frame because all the other pages are working fine.

Comment: Show the full stacktrace.

Comment: `MainFrame` is probably null, but a stack trace would help. This is really up to you to debug though -- with a debugger, it's easy to see what thing is null. I've linked your question to one which has some great advice on finding and fixing NullReferenceExceptions